# Is parallel execution of test is reliable in Web driver and testng in data driven framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I have two classes which have multiple tests. I want to run both classes in parallel. Is the test result reliable?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you have written your tests. Test should be independent of each other and in the order of execution. If your tests confirm this, then you can run them in parallel, but if they share some common resources, that they change, then not, because then the tests are dependant on each other.